# What is the execution model for Solr?

Tags: java, apache, solr, executable-jar

Hi guys : I notice that the Solr installation directory has an executable jar file embedded in the "examples" folder. This is somewhat odd (normally, executables have their own directories - and specific examples would be implemented by having subdirectories with directives, configurations, etc.. )...

For example, we might consider the tomcat, hadoop, or other such server-side programs , which have a single executable that can be launched with a variety of configurations.

1) Im wondering .. do solr deployments compile their own start.jar files from scratch ? If not ... Then why is their no executable in the root solr installation directories.........

2) What is the "execution" model for Solr - do we compile our own versions with our own source code repositories ?  How would we typically manage deployment and administration of solr instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The start.jar is an included version of Jetty, a servlet container. If you execute it, it starts a server at port 8983 with the .war file.

The jetty, example schema.xml, example solrconfig.xml are meant for tutorial purposes.

---

For a production environment, I would deploy the .war file in Tomcat . Tomcat would run fine as a service on bootup. (Even Jetty can be deployed in production).

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat

Setting a Tomcat site:  "my_search":

`http://localhost:8080/my_search`

---

> manage deployment and administration of solr instances

There are solr cores. A simplistic analogy: if a Solr index can be called a big DB table, a Solr core would be a database.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin

Your can set up two cores like:

`http://localhost:8080/my_search/my_classifieds_site`
`http://localhost:8080/my_search/my_doc_search`

You can load/unload a core, swap a running core with a dormant one, swap two running cores without interrupting requests. And they are done with REST operations.

```
http://localhost:8080/my_search/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=coreX&instanceDir=path_to_instance_directory
```

Answer (score 3):

The start.jar file in the example folder is just a quick start way of running Solr with Jetty after you have downloaded it as it needs a servlet container to run in. To answer your questions:

1. There is no executable in the Solr root because it needs to run in a servlet container being that it is a set of REST-like HTTP/XML and JSON APIs.
2. The best answer for this is to check out the [SolrInstall](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall) page on the [Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr), select a servlet container and follow those specific setup instructions.

Comment: Nice and precise answer. Thanks.!